# SSRS URL Access setting a save location?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, urlaccess

We have an SSRS 2012 report we have used URL access in order to automatically save to CSV upon running.  This works fine, However, now I am told they want to force the report to save to a specific folder location for security reasons (they don't want it being saved to desktop) instead of allowing the user to save wherever.  Is there a way to at the very least force a default location using URL access?  Assuming this cannot be accomplished purely through the URL any suggestions for an alternative method?

Comment: A file subscription maybe? Don't know about kicking one off FROM a report though

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the applicable URL parameter commands [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference) in the MS documentation.

That being said, there is no reference to the save location for the export render command that you are using to generate the CSV files. This makes sense because when a website serves a file to download to a browser, the location that the file is saved is actually a browser setting ([IE instructions to change location](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17436/windows-internet-explorer-download-files-from-web))

I see two possible options:

1. Utilize a GPO to target the specific users and modify their registries to set the default download location (note that this affects everything they download).  An example of this tutorial can be found [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8141-change-default-downloads-folder-microsoft-edge-windows-10-a.html#option2).
2. Use a Windows File Share subscription. If you view the report properties and click 'Subscribe', you can setup a file share delivery on a scheduled interval and export as a csv. Note that this is a **schedule** delivery though and obviously won't work if you users need to ad-hoc run the report on their timing.
   [image]